# Get value array in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get value in javascript when input name/id generated by looping, just like this.

```
name="items[1AV08EBfeb][srdnReqQty1AV08EBfeb]"

--js--
var form = document.forms[0];
var get = form.items[1AV08BBjan][srdnReqQty1AV08BBjan].value;

alert(get); //error missing ]

--js--
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks
MRizq

Comment: Always use `id` attribute for html elements

Comment: @Shakti: No, you kind of need `name` if you're going to submit the form element. `id` and `name` serve different purposes, and each has its use.

Comment: ::naveen: i want to get their value and make some condition. ::Shakti Singh: id/name returned same value, id="items[1AV08EBfeb][srdnReqQty1AV08EBfeb]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the name of the element really is

```
name="items[1AV08EBfeb][srdnReqQty1AV08EBfeb]"
```

...as you've shown, then:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
var get = form.elements["items[1AV08EBfeb][srdnReqQty1AV08EBfeb]"].value;
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ikiyih)

There's nothing special about the `[` and `]` characters within the `name` attribute of a form element at the HTML and JavaScript level. Some server-side technologies (like PHP) will look for those characters in the names of submitted form fields and turn them into arrays, but that's not an HTML or JavaScript thing.